# Angular routeProvider is not working in a Single page app

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, single-page-application

I have a small app where I am using the angularjs for routing the calls and dynamically loading the contents of the page...

Here is the angular code I have

```
var amApp = angular.module('amApp', ['ngRoute']);

amApp.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/amlogin.html',
                controller: 'AmController'
            })
            .when('/search/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchController'
            })
            .when('/detail/', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/detail.html',
                controller: 'DetailController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });

amApp.controller('AmController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){
    // Do Something via ajax
}]);
```

And my html is as follows

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#/login">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Login</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And I have a section in my html where i want to load the contents dynamically

```
<section class="content">
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</section>
```

Following are the scripts loaded in the html

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/am-app.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

When I click on the login tab the dynamic content is not loading.
I am not able to find the problem here..
All the scripts are loaded properly and no errors also when I inspect through firebug..

I am new to angular... Any body could help me Please...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Also to add on I have lot of ajax calls that are loaded via jquery... 
Hence I am using those call inside the controller app to load the contents from server side.
amApp.controller('AmController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){
    // Do Something via using jquery apis
}]);

Hope that is not creating any problems

Comment: Is you app called `amApp` or `amazeApp` as you use both, and that will never work!

Comment: Sorry it was a typo... Its amApp not amazeApp...        amApp.controller('AmController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log){ // Do Something via using jquery apis }]);   is the correct code...

Comment: Can anybody suggest a way to debug the problem...?

Comment: if you use jquery ajax, you will need to use `$scope.$apply()`. Better to use angular's $http instead

Comment: Hey Simon Thanks for reply... But no luck the same happening when I remove the jquery ajax call and replaced with a console.log... Still not working...

Comment: you'll need to post your controller